# Delete different number of records from a file in php

Tags: php, file

I have a text file in which 50000 email ids are stored. I need to filter data from this file by deleting email ids of unsubscribes.

I have tried this code but no luck

```
<?php
ini_set("memory_limit","1520M");
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$emails = $_POST['emails'];
$data = $_POST['data'];
$path= $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/data/$data";
$lines = file($path);
$remove = explode("\n",$emails);
foreach ($remove as $rm)
{
foreach($lines as $key => $line)
if(stristr($line, $rm)) unset($lines[$key]);
}
$data1 = implode('', $lines);
$file = fopen($path, "w+");
fwrite($file, $data1);
fclose($file);
?>
```

How can I delete the different number of email ids from a file and keep the other ids remain in file?

txt File contain emails ids as
`shvhsad@domfvh.com
hgffhefg@domnvhg.com
hdewjgweh@domaingfd.com`

........
........

and I need to delete
`hgffhefg@domnvhg.com
hdewjgweh@domaingfd.com`  emails from the file.

Comment: File already returns an array with all lines, so there is no need for the explode by newline

Comment: explode is used because I'm posting the email ids from a form to this page i.e $_POST['emails'] given in the code. Those emails are matched and should be deleted but it is not deleting.

Comment: Can you show an example how exactly your emails are stored?

Comment: Please see  question I have added the example above

Comment: I see, so one email per line. Therefore I was right, no need for that explode. Just use file() then u got an array containing all emails. How do you determinate which email are needed to delete? By that I mean where are the filters coming from and in which format?

Comment: I add the email ids per line to text area in a form and after form submit I get those email to this page using post method

Comment: Let me conclude: all emails are stored in a seperate line, then you post via textarea the E-Mail which have unsubscribed and want to delete those?

Comment: Can you give me code for the same or can correct the code.

Comment: yes you have concluded correctly

Comment: OK good, give me a few minutes

Comment: Hello Manuel, Did you find solution to this.

Comment: Sorry it took me longer then expectet, had a few newline issues, but i came up with a working solution, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
ini_set("memory_limit","1520M");
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// if something has been posted
if (isset($_POST['emails']))
{
    $emails_delete = preg_split('/\r\n|[\r\n]/', $_POST['emails']);
    $emails = file('emails.txt');

    foreach ($emails_delete as $delete)
    {
        $email = trim($delete);

        // check if the email is in the list
        $pos = array_search($email, $emails);
        if (false !== $pos)
        {
            unset($emails[$pos]);
        }

        // save it again
        file_put_contents('emails.txt', $emails);
    }
}
?>
<form action="" method="post">
  <textarea name="emails"></textarea><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
</form>
```

Comment: Hey Manuel, Thanks for your answer but the code is not deleting the email addresses sent from form

Comment: Yeah it only removes it once. Idk whats wrong with it tbh, its some weird newline thingy. May I recommend you using a database? Would make things so much easier $.$

Comment: My email list are stored in a text file

Comment: I know that, but its not to late to store them in a database. Makes things like this very easy, because you dont have to deal with newline etc. I try a few more things, never had that strange behavior..